# CakePHP2.6.4に【CakeDC search-master】プラグインを使って【checkbox】での検索ができない。

Tags: cakephp

`■`MySQLデータベース内に以下のテーブルを作成。

```
create table users(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(250),
    group_id varchar(20));

create table groups(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(250));
```

`■`サンプルとして、30レコードほど入力済み

`■`Search Pluginを設定済み

`■`app/Model/User.php

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

public $belongsTo = array(              
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $filterArgs = array(
    'name' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' =>
        array('User.name','User.group_id')));
    }
```

`■`app/Model/Group.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Group extends AppModel {

public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
      )
   );
}
```

`■`app/Controller/UsersController.php

```
<?php
  class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Search.Prg');
    public $paginate = array();

    public function index() {
            $this->Prg->commonProcess();
            $this->paginate = array(
                    'limit' => 5
            );

            $this->paginate['conditions'] = $this->User->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);

            $userList = $this->paginate();
            $this->set(compact('userList'));

            $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
            $this->set(compact( 'groups'));
      }
}
```

`■`app/View/Users/index.ctp

```
<div class="section form_search">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array(
    'novalidate' => true,
    'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index'),
     $this->params['pass'])));
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name',array('placeholder' => '名前を入力してください','lable' => false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('group_id', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $groups,
    ));
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('検索'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

<div class="section">
<h2>名前 or グループ名一覧</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id','ID'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name','名前'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('group_id','グループ'); ?></th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach($userList as $user): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['id']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['name']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($user['Group']['name']); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>

<div class="paginateLinks">
  <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev(); ?>
  <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
  <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(); ?>
</div>
```

以上で、全てです。

ユーザーの名前を入力しての検索は、できるのですが、チェックボックス
にチェックを入れて検索ができません。

どうすれば、チェックボックスでの検索ができるのでしょうか？

それと、名前とチェックボックスのAND検索。
名前とチェックボックスのOR検索もどうすれば良いか
いろいろやってみたのですが、CakePHP初心者には、
いつまでたっても分かりません。

どうか、よろしくおお願いします。